# Are there any Libertarian schools?

Tags: united-states, education, libertarianism

I did some web searches and could not find any examples of a Libertarian school. In fact, there were no examples I could find of any political-oriented schools in the United States. There only seemed to be religious schools.

Comment: Are you asking if there's a school that provides general education while pressing a Libertarian agenda, or a school specifically on Libertarian politics, or...?

Comment: @Nat The first one.

Comment: You might check the [free state project](https://freestateproject.org/) to see if they know of a majority libertarian school district in New Hampshire.  I don't know that there are any single party schools the way that there are single religion schools.

Comment: Libertarian isn't an education method so the term "libertarian schools" is vague, but there are charter schools that have been founded by libertarians http://reason.com/reasontv/2017/01/23/thales-academy-north-carolina-bob-luddy

Comment: What's the background to this question? Do you come from an area where schools are commonly affiliated with a political party? Why did you expect to find a Libertarian-affiliated school in the United States?

Answer (score 4):

There is a strong tendency towards homeschooling coops among committed Libertarians.

The [Acton Academy](https://www.actonacademy.org/) network of schools has concepts that are attractive to many Libertarians. The same applies to the [Sudbury Valley](https://sudburyvalley.org/) school concept. Libertarian families are often also attracted to Reggio Emilia and Montessori schools, depending on the local community.

Comment: Hello, welcome to politics SE! Please read the [tour] and [answer], as they are important, and feel free to join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6619/agora) once you can.

Answer (score 2):

Closest to libertarian you can get is the Mises University by [Mises Institute](https://mises.org/). in Auburn, Alabama.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many (or really any I could find which were libertarian, as opposed to conservative with free-market economics department like Hillsdale or Grove City).

- [Institute for Humane Studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institute_for_Humane_Studies) is not a fully fledged school in and out of itself, but is a libertarian educational non-profit associated with George Mason University.
- While not strictly speaking "libertarian" in a political sense, University of Chicago Economic department is of course the source of [Chicago School of Economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_school_of_economics), one of the most notable sources of neoliberal economic outlook in USA (including such notables as Milton Friedman)

Comment: @userLTK - with all due respect, did you even bother reading that hatchet job of an "article" besides the headline? There's absolutely **nothing** in the information provided that even remotely hints at "libertarian" (aside from some nebulous connection to the boogeyman evil Koch brothers). The only firm piece of information provided (pledge to "respect authority") is *literally about as far removed from libertarian as you can possibly get*..

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you consider the Koch brothers libertarian?   Because they consider themselves that.   David Koch ran as the libertarian VP candidate in 1980.   The Kochs are championing charter schools.

Comment: @userLTK - Yes. I fail to see how that in any way shape or form makes either that, or any other charter school, a "libertarian school" (other than the whole concept of non-state-owned school in general being more libertarian than state owned schools)

Comment: @userLTK - the only reason that word is in the article is because the authoritarian progressive "journalist" who wrote that page wanted to smear libertarian-ism by trying to associate it with a dude who clearly likes to go around rules.

Comment: It was a bad article, and I've deleted it, but I still want to know.   Are the Koch brothers libertarians in your opinion?  Because one of them ran on the libertarian ticket some years back and they're big backers of charter schools.

Comment: @userLTK - they self-identify as such, and their stated views (based on "Freakonomics" podcast interview) seem to match, so I would say "yes". But I can't honestly say I ever bothered researching enough to be sure.

Comment: Fair enough - thanks for answering.    I'll delete my comments in a day or two, as I don't think they add anything to your answer.